# Execution time of a Prepared statement's executeQuery() method vs. corresponding Stored procedure execution time

Tags: java, postgresql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

I have some middleware java code running on a Server machine that calls a Stored procedure `insertMessageOne` in a Postgresql database (9.1) on a remote machine.

```
PreparedStatement sendOne = con.prepareStatement(
            "SELECT insertMessageOne(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

// Following is the call to Stored procedure through PreparedStatement sendOne
long start = System.nanoTime();
ResultSet rs = sendOne.executeQuery();
long end = System.nanoTime();
long elapsed = (end - start)/1000000;
fileLog.write(System.currentTimeMillis() + ": " + "sendOne.executeQuery(): " + elapsed + "\n");
```

From the logs, I can see that the executeQuery takes a few tens of milliseconds.

```
1385732177920: sendOne.executeQuery(): 13 
1385732178331: sendOne.executeQuery(): 20
1385732178436: sendOne.executeQuery(): 23
```

However, for the Stored Procedure insertMessageOne (code follows):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insertMessageOne(sender_id INT, receiver_id INT, queue_id INT, context INT, priority INT, text varchar(2000))
RETURNS BOOLEAN 
AS $$
DECLARE
    start timestamp;
    stop timestamp;
BEGIN
    start = clock_timestamp();
    INSERT INTO message(sender_id, receiver_id, queue_id, context, priority, text) VALUES($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6);
    stop = clock_timestamp();
    RAISE NOTICE 'Timestamp: (%) senderId: (%) insertMessageOne: (%)', stop, sender_id, stop - start;
    RETURN TRUE;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'EXCEPTION: INSERT SINGLE-Q MESSAGE FAILED';
        RETURN FALSE;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

the execution time of the Stored procedure as seen in logs is very small (less than 1-2 ms):

```
NOTICE:  Timestamp: (2013-11-29 15:29:06.012125) senderId: (49) insertMessageOne: (00:00:00.000684)                                                    
NOTICE:  Timestamp: (2013-11-29 15:29:06.012848) senderId: (16) insertMessageOne: (00:00:00.000702)                                                    
NOTICE:  Timestamp: (2013-11-29 15:29:06.013465) senderId: (10) insertMessageOne: (00:00:00.000617)
```

Why is the execution time of the executeQuery so large as compared to the corresponding execution time of the Stored procedure? Network latency/bandwidth should not be an issue in this case, because the code was run on machines in a cluster (directly connected to each other). Is there some step (between `executeQuery()` call and the actual execution of the Stored procedure `insertMessageOne()`) that I need to take into account?

Comment: It's the network that's causing a few milliseconds of latency. Verify by running your Java program directly on your Postgres server. Or just ping your Postgres server and look at average response time. On my gigabit lan it's an average `0.304 ms` to the router but localhost averages `0.034 ms`.

Comment: I just checked the average response time. It is 0.183 ms on average, which does not explain the difference of almost 10 milliseconds in the two execution times. I am guessing there is something going on behind the scenes when executeQuery() is called. JDBC driver adds some overhead, maybe?

Comment: Possibly. You might want to see if `CallableStatement` has the same performance. There's always `addBatch()` and `executeBatch()` to consider as well.

Comment: If the connection is in autoCommit mode, that would be the reason.

Comment: JDBC know server side and client side prepared statements - and what I know, JDBC driver starts with client side PP and after some repeating use server side. On second hand, you newer can get a speed of stored procedures - there are no network layers overhead, and PostgreSQL stored procedures are executed as inprocess (in database engine)

Comment: @DanielVérité: The connection is in autoCommit mode (the default ). Could you please elaborate more? How is autocommit mode related to my observations in the question? Is it that the changes to the database are committed after the stored procedure finishes, and therefore time to commit the changes can't be measured from inside the stored procedure? P.S: You can probably add your reply as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The duration of the INSERT measured from inside the function does not include a commit, because postgres never commits implicitly inside a function (or even explicitly, a COMMIT statement would raise an error inside the function if you tried).

If the JDBC connection is in autoCommit mode, which means from the point of view of the server that the client didn't issue an SQL `BEGIN` starting a transaction, then postgres will create itself an "internal" transaction for the duration of the query, and commit at its end.

10-20ms is typical of the time needed to commit on normal disks, so it seems plausible that it accounts for the time difference you're seeing.

If you'd group the series of INSERTs inside a single transaction, this delay should be much lower (there's still the network overhead as discussed in the comments)

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. In fact, I was puzzled why do I see those differences only for 'insert' message (changes the database) and not for reading messages (a simple select that doesn't change the database). Now, I know why.

Comment: Probably, you know the answer to this related question too, I just posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20331371/postgres-9-1-measure-time-taken-for-a-transaction-including-commit