# Postgres 9.1: Measure time taken for a transaction (including commit)

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, logging, transactions

I have the following stored procedure, insertMessageOne:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insertMessageOne(sender_id INT, receiver_id INT, queue_id INT, context INT, priority INT, text varchar(2000))
RETURNS BOOLEAN 
AS $$
DECLARE
    start timestamp;
    stop timestamp;
BEGIN
    start = clock_timestamp();
    INSERT INTO message(sender_id, receiver_id, queue_id, context, priority, text) VALUES($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6);
    stop = clock_timestamp();
    RAISE NOTICE 'Timestamp: (%) senderId: (%) insertMessageOne: (%)', stop, sender_id, stop - start;
    RETURN TRUE;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'EXCEPTION: INSERT SINGLE-Q MESSAGE FAILED';
        RETURN FALSE;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

As seen above, I measure the execution time for this stored procedure using start and stop timestamps at the beginning and end of the stored procedure. However, as the actual transaction commit happens *after* the stored procedure ends, the time logged is off by 10-20 ms (See [Execution time of a Prepared statement's executeQuery() method vs. corresponding Stored procedure execution time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20307375/execution-time-of-a-prepared-statements-executequery-method-vs-corresponding)) typically required for committing a transaction. How can I log the time that includes time taken for committing the transaction as well? pgBench is probably not good enough for me, because I want these numbers when an actual live application (from middleware) calls this stored procedure.

Comment: Have you tried enabling timing for `psql` and sending a query from it?

Comment: Can't you log the durations in the middleware?

Comment: middleware logging would include the network latency as well. To exclude it, logging would have to be done in the database itself.

Answer (score 0):

There is no facility for doing exactly this in PostgreSQL.   For a transaction time also keep in mind you may have additional idle time waiting for more commands, so your best option really if you want to get an idea of how a transaction performs is to enable timing in psql and run it on the same server as the db server, and over UNIX sockets.  You still have IPC overhead but no network latency in that case.  You could run on a copy of your production db, or you could write your own scripts in, say, Perl that run the transaction, time it, and roll it back.

Your other option is to enable durations on the middleware which may be a good idea too but as you say also gives you network latency.  You could measure network latency though and correct for it in your final calculations.

Answer (score -1):

```
select timeofday();
```

transaction would be like::

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_name()

RETURNS json AS

$BODY$

declare

BEGIN

select timeofday();

/*code lies here*/

select timeofday()

return v_json;

END

$BODY$

  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE

  COST 100;
```